# Some diacritic characters disappear on Android (Unity)

Tags: android, internationalization, unity-game-engine

I've made a game in Unity which uses three languages (Dutch, Polish and English) and can both be played on PC and on Android. But on Android all Polish characters (ĄĆĘŃŚŹŻ) disappear except for these two characters: Ł & Ó. Does someone know what I could do to fix this? And before anyone asks I'm using a Unicode supported font.

Comment: How are you storing the Polish diacritic characters? How do you reference these characters in the main part of your app? Show your codes so we can help you.

Comment: Currently I'm hardcoding the strings in my code like: someGUIelement.text = "some polish text with diacritics: ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ";

Comment: Did my answer below help you? Or, are you still stuck?

Comment: I tried with the unicode code but it failed on Android... And I know Android uses Java, but I'm making it in Unity with C#. Both the unicode written and hard coded letters disappear on Android.

Comment: I don't know Microsoft C#, but according to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), C# writes Unicode characters the same as Java. Might be a problem with Unity if it can't render escaped Unicode characters. When you debug Unity, does it show the actual Unicode characters in debug mode?

Comment: In Unity itself and on Windows you see the unicode characters normally. F.i. when in the code is written: "\u0106" then I will see "Ć" in the Unity debug and on the built Windows application, but it will not appear at all on Android. Maybe if I would get the values from a file or something then maybe it will also work on Android. I let you know if it succeeds.

Comment: Are you saving your source file as UTF-8 with byte order mark (BOM)? By default, Unity's C# compiler won't automatically treat a source file as UTF-8 unless you tell it to. Also, when you compile, can you try using `-codepage:utf8` switch when calling the MCS compiler. Without the `-codepage` switch, the compiler default to whatever encoding that is native for the platform it's running on.

Comment: The strings are not saved in a file (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you hardcoded the characters in your app, then you need to do something like:

For Java (Note: Android is using Java)

1. Write **Ą** as **\u0104**
2. Write **Ć** as **\u0106**
3. Write **Ł** as **\u0141**
4. Write **Ó** as **\u00d3**

and so on.

For HTML / XML

1. Write **Ą** as **&#x104;**
2. Write **Ć** as **&#x106;**
3. Write **Ł** as **&#x141;**
4. Write **Ó** as **&#x00d3;**

and so on.

Search [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0107/index.htm) for the equivalent unicode and hexadecimal values for the other Polish diacritic characters.

Also, when compiling source codes under Unity, you may need to provide the `-codepage:utf8` switch when calling the MCS compiler. Otherwise, the compiler will default to whatever encoding the OS platform is using.