# lao keyboard is not proper in android

Tags: android, southeast-asian-languages

```
private String sL[] = { "ຢ", "ຟ", "ໂ", "ຖ", "ຄ", "ຕ", "ຈ", "ຂ", "ຊ",
        "ໄ", "ພ", "ະ", "ຮ", "ນ", "ຍ", "ບ", "ລ", "ຫ", "ກ", "ດ",
        "ເ", "າ", "ສ", "ວ", "ງ", "ຜ", "ປ", "ແ", "ອ", "ທ", "ມ", "ໃ" };
private String cL[] = { "ຶ", "້", "ື", "້", "ຸ", "ູ", "້", "໊", "໋",
        "ໍ", "ົ", "ຳ", "ິ", "ີ", "ັ", "້", "່", "ຶ", "ື", "໌",
        "ຼ", "ໍ", "່", "ົ", "້", "ຳ", "້", "ິ", "້", "ີ", "້", "ັ" };
```

In my dictionary, I set font for keyboard. character from sL array is working fine.. but when I setting characters from cL array, at that time..nothing is displaying on button.. help me for that

Comment: I think you need fonts with those gliphs. Not sure what font has lao, though.

Comment: I already used font for that..thats why character from sl is working..

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059128/some-diacritic-characters-disappear-on-android-unity/21072079#21072079) here. The OP in that post had similar issues with Unicode characters like you do.